# How to (force) use Nvidia graphics with OpenShot?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hardware-acceleration, openshot

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 . Yesterday I slightly edited a video in OpenShot, but video exporting was too slow, like it will take forever to finish!

So now I want to use my Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti, but I don't know how to enable OpenShot to use GPU. By default, OpenShot doesn't use GPU rendering.

Also, I downloaded Openshot 2 months ago, so it is almost the latest version.

Even though I have Nvidia Xserver and Nvidia running (performance mode enabled), none of the applications (browsers etc) seem to be using it, so practically there is no use in enabling Nvidia.

How to make use of the Nvidia card ?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenShot 2.5.0 introduced an *experimental* support for hardware acceleration.](https://www.openshot.org/en/blog/2020/02/08/openshot-250-released-video-editing-hardware-acceleration/)

[Openshot 2.5.1](https://www.openshot.org/en/download/) is currently available for Ubuntu as Appimage. Provided the recommended Nvidia driver version is correctly installed and loading/working and the video format is supported (cf. image in the 1st link), GPU acceleration should happen automatically.

```
I have Nvidia Xserver and Nvidia running (performance mode enabled), but none of the applications (browsers etc) seem using it, so practically there is no use of enabling Nvidia.
```

This affirmation is false. With Performance Mode enabled ALL software is using the dGPU Nvidia.

Whether or not it makes any noticeable difference is a separate issue and it depends entirely on any given software supporting hardware acceleration. We browsers in Linux, as mentioned in the question, typically don't or didn't until recently:

- Chromium Developer version (from PPA): YES (experimental)
- Chrome: MAYBE? (probably yes, very experimental)
- Firefox: MAYBE? (probably not yet)

The difference is quite noticeable when running modern games. And games, rather than productivity is, at the end of the day, *la raison d'être* of Nvidia Geforce GTX1050Ti. It is a good, average, gaming graphics card, far from exceptional.

Comment: Even I used `NVENC` (cuz other green options not working, they say: "`Could not create hwdevice`" ), still there is no speed in rendering. It its very slow. Though I see that GPU usage goes to 12% from 8% (570 MB from 340 MB).